# How to compile and run java file through processbuider with multiple command?

Tags: java

```
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac Test.java"); 
   Process q = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Test");
   p.waitFor(); 

   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(q.getInputStream())); 
   String line; 
   while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
       System.out.println(line); 
   }
```

this not works......Also it not returns the errors and output. 
Also I want to ask what is better process or processbuilder

Answer (score 1):

Your code starts both the `javac` and the `java` processes together. Of course, if the `javac` process is still working, you should not try to run `java` on its result.

So you should put your `p.waitFor()` *before* you create process `q`, and only create process `q` if process `p` succeeded.

To know whether `p` succeeded or not, you should check the return code of the process, after the `waitFor()`:

```
int exitVal = p.exitValue();
```

If it wasn't zero, you can check the errors by reading *the error stream*. Currently, you are trying to get the input stream (which is the process's output stream). But errors are printed to the error stream (just as you would use `System.err.println()` in your own programs). To get that, you need to call `p.getErrorStream()` rather than `p.getInputStream()`, and then read it and print it.

If the `exitVal` was zero, and only then, you can create the other process, because you know that compilation succeed and you have a `.class` file waiting to be ran.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to RealSkeptics answer you might want to have a look at the tools.jar that comes with the JDK. It includes a version of javac you can directly call and that is thus easier to debug.

And there are other runtime compilers out there. The one that comes with Eclipse for example.